# How can I change the view value for input but not the real modal value via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an ID input box, I want to mask first 4 digits of that field but when I submit I still need to submit with the real data.

Currently what I'm doing is:

```
    maskInputVal($input) {
    // Mask client id first 4 numbers with XXXX eg. XXXX4323 (real data is 23434323)
    let currentInputValue = $input.val();
    if (currentInputValue && currentInputValue.length > 4) {
        input.val(currentInputValue.replace(/^.{4}/g, 'XXXX'));
    }
}
```

But in this way the real value is changed. So when I submit it won't submit with 23434323 but XXXX4323.

How can I just change the view value via JQuery?

Comment: store the value in other variable before replacing

Comment: you could either use @Vineesh answer or modify your html, so the first 4 digits is an input with a type of password and the rest is text. While submitting you just submit both

Answer (score 0):

Before masking the value, keep the value in some hidden field. Then use  the value from the hidden field for processing.

```
maskInputVal($input) {
    // Mask client id first 4 numbers with XXXX eg. XXXX4323 (real data is 23434323)
    let currentInputValue = $input.val();
    $("#some_hidden_field").val(currentInputValue);
    if (currentInputValue && currentInputValue.length > 4) {
        input.val(currentInputValue.replace(/^.{4}/g, 'XXXX'));
    }
}
```

Comment: why you need a DOM element to store a value?

Comment: If you are storing in JS variable it won't be available after form submit.

Comment: *when I submit I still need to submit with the real data* so he need to store it in another hidden input . @Durga

Comment: @JYoThI he dosnt want to store the value after form submit, he want to submit that real data only, m I right?

Comment: yes he want submit the real data . so he need to keep the real data in some hidden input field . so that when form submit we will get the real data from that hidden input filed . @Durga

Comment: Thanks. But how can I know when trigger submit, it will submit with the hidden input value as the client ID instead of the exposed one?

Comment: For example suppose your field name is `ClientID`, then give the hidden field name as `ClientID` and the one which shows as `ClientID-masked`. So while submitting you can always take the value from `ClientID` field